# Problem with opening a script tag with < and &lt; through a CMS

Tags: html, css, tags, content-management-system, liferay-7

I have a problem trying to put a small matomo tracking script on an old version (7.1) of the LifeRay CMS, of course I'm no coding expert.
Using a function of the CMS we have a field we are supposed to use to inject a specific script/code within every page of the website.

Problem is that when I use this field, whatever I write inside gets read as plain text.
After some time I found out the possible cause by examining the body through Chrome dev console.
What should be a `<script>` tag, is actually there as `&lt;script&gt;` .
The same happens for the closing tag of course.

By manually editing the html through the Chrome console and simply fixing those characters with "<" and ">" everything works perfectly, but I'm wondering... how can I fix this regularly and not just in the temporary chrome console?
I really have no clue what could be causing this in the CMS.
(I have other VMs with different websites and the same LifeRay version and there copy/pasting the script worked flawlessly)

I checked the page through and through and there are no other instances of "<" and ">" being swapped with those other strings.

Comment: So apparently the output is getting escaped, with the explicit purpose of _not_ getting any HTML code interpreted, but only shown _in_ code form. _"Using a function of the CMS we have a field we are supposed to use to inject a specific script/code within every page of the website."_ - probably something to do with how exactly you did that then, so - we need more details.

Comment: There's a specific field in Liferay 7.1 to handle analytics implementations. It's in Configuration > Website Settings > Advanced.
There are basically two sections, one is for Google Analytics, where you input specific parts and the CMS creates the final script that gets injected in the page, or there's a second option for Piwik. Whatever you write in this field gets injected in the first part of the body section of every page of the website.
Since I'm using a matomo-based platform, I simply put the script code there. As a matter of fact it works fine on other Liferay 7.1 websites I manage.

Comment: It's appearently a known bug on that specific subversion of 7.1 which is slightly different from my other 7.1 websites and hence why I'm getting no issue there.